# sed command returning "sed: bad option in substitution expression"

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, script, sed

For example:- I have a file named file.txt

```
$ cat file.txt
$key
```

I have a environment variable, for eg: $key in a text file

and lets say $key = 1234, so I can replace the value with the below command

```
sed -i 's/$key/'"$key"'/' file.txt
```

and it becomes

```
$ cat file.txt
1234
```

My problem is that if the value for

```
$key = 1/2/3/4
```

I'm not able to run the below command

```
sed -i 's/$key/'"$key"'/' file.txt
```

It will give an error

```
sed: bad option in substitution expression
```

Because of the slash it's breaking. I can solve it by giving the value directly but I don't want to use it in that way.

```
sed -i 's/$key/1\/2\/3\/4/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem has to do with the fact that the `sed` delimiter is `/` and it collides with the text in `$key`. To solve it, use another delimiter. For example, `#`:

```
$ key="1/2/3/4"
$ echo 1/2/3/4 | sed "s#$key#\"$key\"#" 
"1/2/3/4"
```

Or

```
$ echo "hello this is 1/2/3/4 yeah" | sed "s#$key#\"$key\"#"
hello this is "1/2/3/4" yeah
```

Interesting reading: [What delimiters can you use in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33914360/1983854). Spoiler: almost everything!

Comment: The problem is when you don't know what characters the variable will contain.

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -pe 's/\$([[:alnum:]]+)/$ENV{$1}/'
```

Explanation:

- `\$` matches the dollar sign.
- `[[:alnum:]]` matches digits, letters and underscore, i.e. valid identifier characters. The `+` means there must be at least one such character.
- `(...)` introduces a capture group.
- `$ENV{$1}` retrieves the value from the `%ENV` hash which contains the environment variables. Perl doesn't expand variables like shell, so the variable can contain `/` (or whatever else) without harm.

Example:

```
$ echo '$key' | key=1/2/3/4 perl -pe 's/\$([[:alnum:]]*)/$ENV{$1}/'
1/2/3/4
```